# How to set a default page on Azure Web App

Tags: html, asp.net, azure, iis, web-config

I'm having a problem with a redirect to a default page.

I have `https://url.to.azure.website.net` but when I just go to this page it responds with a 403 forbidden.
I know this is due to a missing default page.

However when I go to `https://url.to.azure.website.net/en/home.html`, I do get my home page.

How can I set my default page to direct straight to the `/nl/home.html` ?

Little extra: Is it possible to not show the ".html" extension in the url?

Answer (score 6):

Web Apps allow you to specify the default page. You'll find this in the various settings:

[image: default documents]

However: This isn't going to let you specify a virtual directory path, such as `/en` or `/nl` as you have shown. You'll need to deal with redirects within your app / routes / etc.

Comment: do you have more insight on how to redirect it ?

Comment: as David mentioned, you can't redirect to a file from a virtual directory; I ended up setting the Default document to "default.html" and added this file to the root. Default.html contains only a script that redirects to the desired file: window.location = "./myVirtualDirectory/actualDefaultDoc.html"

Answer (score -4):

To redirect, go to code behind in your default.aspx page and use Response.Redirect.