# Avoid index.html in Azure url

Tags: .net, azure, vue.js, azure-web-app-service, .net-4.8

I've published on Azure a .NET Framework 4.8 web application (which front end is made in Vue.js 2). If I go to https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/ it shows an error page with the following message:

"*Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.*"

Instead if I add index.html in the path (https://XXX.azurewebsites.net/index.html) I can see the login page of my web app. How can I avoid to add index.html in the url?

Comment: Hi ! Have you set the default page (index.html) in your website configuration ? Perhaps it's something else. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40704310/4698373

Comment: Hi @Philippe, yes, I have index.html in the default documents list

Comment: Sorry @andref94 if it is a poor additional question, but don't you have to select one of them in the list ? Or perhaps a routing issue in your web app configuration. The working direct access to your page via its url, means that the code inside seems to be correct.

Comment: It's a simple list, I can't select one of the items. index.html is the only file of the ones in the list that I also have in my project folder. While developing on my pc I can access the webapp from localhost:8080 without index.html in the path, so I don't think that it's a routing problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem was caused by a configuration of the mvc application. In global.asax file there is a call to a static method:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollections routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I've removed the MapRoute method call and everything has started working as expected

Comment: "route or no route" ;) Glad to read you pointed out the origin of the issue. It sounds like it will help other people.